# Can you update statistics on a sys change tracking table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, statistics, change-tracking

I'm tracking down some poor query times doing the typical query to get changed records:

```
select StoreItemId from changetable(changes [dbo].[StoreItem], @clientChangeTrackingVs) as ChangedRow where [StoreId] = @storeId;
```

The execution plan shows a clustered index scan instead of a clustered index seek on the sys change tracking table exactly as described in this article:

https://port1433.com/2015/01/29/change_tracking_table_statistics/

In that article it suggests:

> Could it really by so simple as:
>
> UPDATE STATISTICS sys.change_tracking_315968302 Sure enough, that did
>   the trick. The plan instantly got happier.

My login is running with full control granted, but that still will not let me run that command agaonst a sys table:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS sys.change_tracking_1198627313

Msg 1088, Level 16, State 12, Line 1
Cannot find the object "sys.change_tracking_1198627313" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Is it possible to run this command, or otherwise force a seek instead of a scan?  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

---

Edit1:  Adding the scan image

[image]

---

Edit 2:  Just to confirm that the scan vs seek was causing the slowdown, I applied a `WITH (FORCESEEK)`.  This took me a while to figure out, because `changetable` is not a table so the syntax was invalid.  I managed to use a CTE and then make the syntax work:

```
WITH ChangedRowCTE (StoreId, StoreItemId)
AS
(
    select StoreId, StoreItemId from changetable(changes [dbo].[StoreItem], @clientChangeTrackingVs) as ChangedRow
)
select 
   StoreItemId
from 
   ChangedRowCTE WITH (FORCESEEK)
where [StoreId] = storeId;
```

Execution planned shows the seek and execution time was 4 times faster.

---

Edit 3:

This is what I meant by full control:

The following describes the general conventions that are followed for naming permissions:

> CONTROL
>
> Confers ownership-like capabilities on the grantee. The grantee
>   effectively has all defined permissions on the securable. A principal
>   that has been granted CONTROL can also grant permissions on the
>   securable. Because the SQL Server security model is hierarchical,
>   CONTROL at a particular scope implicitly includes CONTROL on all the
>   securables under that scope. **For example, CONTROL on a database
>   implies all permissions on the database**, all permissions on all
>   assemblies in the database, all permissions on all schemas in the
>   database, and all permissions on objects within all schemas within the
>   database.

That being said, I asked the sys admin to run this command and he stated he was able to run the command.  So I guess the answer to my own question is "yes" you can, but you have to be the admin.

Comment: Is change tracking enabled for the [dbo].[StoreItem] table? Based on the error, I'd suspect either it isn't or change tracking as a whole is not on.

Comment: Oh yes, it is on.  The select query first listed runs and returns results.  It is just running slower than expected / normal.  I'll attach an image from the query plan that shows the scan instead of the seek.

Comment: What do you mean your login has "Full Control", is your login a sysadmin, db_owner?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  I edited to answer your question and update the most recent status of the issue (the question was from last week).